# r function to pmml success but not recognized in container

Tags: r, pmml

Here is an example of R script using a couple of library

```
library(pmml)
library(pmmlTransformations)
data(iris)
irisBox <- WrapData(iris)
irisBox <- FunctionXform(irisBox,origFieldName="Sepal.Length",
           newFieldName="Sepal.Length.Transformed",
           formulaText="ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,Sepal.Length*1.2, Sepal.Length*.8)")
mod1 <- lm(Sepal.Length.Transformed ~ Petal.Length, irisBox$data)
pmml(mod1, transform = irisBox)
```

The function works fine and create a nice pmml output. However, the ifelse statement is not the recognizable function in pmml 4_3. Can anybody recommend an alternative to the above script to generate pmml workable command?

I recognize that DiscretizeXform is recommended in the pmmlTransformations package but it is very cumbersome so I am reluctant to use since it has to read breakpoints from outside files.

Comment: What does it mean when you write: " the ifelse statement is not the recognizable function in pmml 4_3"?

Comment: "if" is a buildin function according to the pmml 4-3 document but not 'ifelse'. So when I execute pmml in the container, it shows an error message : org.jpmml.manager.UnsupportedFeatureException (at or around line 217): Apply@function=ifelse

Comment: This makes no sense: `is.function(ifelse)`; #[1]TRUE. It's in the `base` package so it should always be available.

Comment: I'm finally understanding this. Your complaint was that some external processing step was the problem _after_ the R program parsed your code and model and had no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pmmlTransformations` package does not know how to handle the "ifelse" R function, and passes it through as-is. That's why the resulting PMML document contains `Apply@function="ifelse"` when it should be containing `Apply@function="if"`.

The [PMML "if" built-in function](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/BuiltinFunctions.html#boolean6) is perfectly able to represent if-else branching logic:

> Implements IF-THEN-ELSE logic. The ELSE part is optional. If the ELSE part is absent and the boolean value is false then a missing value is returned.

As for a solution, then please consider switching to the [`r2pmml` package](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml), which lets you do feature engineering inside formulas (as opposed to "boxing" `data.frame` objects), including full support for the "ifelse" R function:

```
library("randomForest")
library("r2pmml")

iris.rf = randomForest(Species ~ ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,Sepal.Length*1.2, Sepal.Length*.8) + ., data = iris)

r2pmml(iris.rf, "iris.pmml")
```

Comment: Can you also provide R script for pmml package with 'if' statement to replace 'ifelse' statement?  I understand and use r2pmml method as you mentioned, but I have numerous layer of feature manipulation before I apply a model to the derived features. Thanks!

Comment: The "ifelse" function is a vectorized operation, whereas the "if" function isn't. This distinction is important when working with R formulas.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple replacement would work.

```
irisBox <- WrapData(iris)
irisBox <- FunctionXform(irisBox,origFieldName="Sepal.Length",
       newFieldName="Sepal.Length.Transformed",
       formulaText="if(Sepal.Length>5) Sepal.Length*1.2 else Sepal.Length*.8")
mod1 <- lm(Sepal.Length.Transformed ~ Petal.Length, irisBox$data)
pmml(mod1, transform = irisBox)
```

Comment: You could have achieved an identical outcome by manually replacing `function="ifelse"` with `function="if"` in the produced PMML document. Sure, now you have it automated, which is even better.